# Issues while loading JSON in Azure Notebooks

Tags: json, scala, pyspark, azure-synapse

Recently I've been trying to make some transformations in some Json files in the Azure Synapse notebooks using Scala language and loading them in using the **spark.read** function. The problem is the following one:

- 1st case: I load it using an schema (via *Structype*) and the returned DF is all null
- 2nd case: I load it withouth the schema and it returns "*_corrupt_record*" (this happens using multiline = true, too)

I do not know what is happening as I have tried to load different types of Jsons and none of them work (they are normal jsons downloaded from Kaggle, though).

```js
{
  "results": [{
    "columns": [{
      "name": "COD",
      "type": "NUMBER"
    }, {
      "name": "TECH",
      "type": "NUMBER"
    }, {
      "name": "OBJECT",
      "type": "NUMBER"
    }],
    "items": [{
      "cod": 3699,
      "tech": "-",
      "object": "Type 2"
    }, {
      "cod": 3700,
      "tech": 56,
      "object": "Type 1"
    }, {
      "cod": 3701,
      "tech": 20,
      "object": "No type"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Are you loading json file from adls?

Comment: can you please provide sample data?

Comment: @PratikLad I am loading it from a folder of my filesystem of the Data Lake Storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting similar kind of corrupt data error when I tried to reproduce

[image]

**As you shared sample data it contains multiple lines to single object and the Json has multiple objects inside it to view this Json file, I used the `multiline` option as `true` and the exploded each column and selected it.**

```scala
//reading JSON file from ADLS in json format
val  read_path = "abfss://fsn2p@dlsg2p.dfs.core.windows.net/sample.json"
val  customers_data_path = spark.read.format("json").option("inferSchema","true").option("multiline","true").load(read_path)
customers_data_path.show();
```

[image]

```scala
//Exploding the results column into its object as column
val  DF1=customers_data_path.select(explode(col("results")).as("results"))
DF1.show()

//Selecting all columns from results
val  DF2 = DF1.select(col("results.*"))
DF2.show();
```

[image]

```scala
//further exploding Columns column and items objects
val  DF3 = DF2.select(explode(col("columns")).as("columns"),col("items"))
val  DF4 = DF3.select(col("columns"),explode(col("items")).as("items"))
DF4.show();
```

[image]

1. **In this approach you will each item object has all columns object value**

```scala
//selecting All columns inside columns and items object
val  DF5 = DF4.select(col("columns.*"),col("items.*"))
DF5.show();
```

[image]

2. **In this approach you will get null when object dont have value in particular colum.**

```scala
//exploding Columns column and items objects
val  DF5 = DF2.select(explode(col("columns")).as("columns"))
DF5.show();

val  DF6 = DF2.select(explode(col("items")).as("items"))
DF6.show();
```

[image]

```scala
//selecting All columns inside columns and items object
val  DF7 = DF5.select(col("columns.*"))
val  DF8 = DF6.select(col("items.*"))
DF7.show();
DF8.show();
```

[image]

```scala
//combining both the above dataframes 
val  DF10 = DF7.join(DF8, lit(false), "full").show()
```

[image]

3. **In this approach you will get combined data frame for columns**

```scala
//creating sequential index column with help of that join the data frames and then drop it.

import  org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, LongType};
import  spark.implicits._
import  org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val  df11 = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
DF7.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
case (row, index) =>  Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index)
},
// Create schema for index column
StructType(DF7.schema.fields :+ StructField("index", LongType, false))
)

val  df22 = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
DF8.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
case (row, index) =>  Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index)
},
// Create schema for index column
StructType(DF8.schema.fields :+ StructField("index", LongType, false))
)

val  DF12 = df11.join(df22, Seq("index")).drop("index")

DF12.show()
```

[image]

[image]